# OpenCV.js - Create a RectVector object for CascadeClassifier

Tags: javascript, opencv

I'm trying to implement the use of `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` for facial recognition via OpenCV.js. However, when I'm trying to use the `detectMultiScale()` method of the `CascadeClassifier` object it expects to have an argument of the type of `RectVector`, but I am unable to find a way to instantiate such an object.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var face_cascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

function face_detector() {
    var imgElement = document.getElementById("test");
    var img = cv.imread(imgElement);
    cv.cvtColor(img, img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, faces); //faces needs to be an obj of RectVector type
    //window.alert(faces.length);
}
```

In my code, I need `faces` to be an object of type `RectVector` but I don't know how. Any pointers will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `RectVector` object as below:

```
var faces = new cv.RectVector();
```

For tutorials for opencv using JavaScript as your programming language you could have a look [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/doc/js_tutorials). Especially [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/doc/js_tutorials/js_assets/js_face_detection.html) you would find a tutorial for face detection.